# How do I lock access to a dll while making calls from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

My asp.net webapi application fails when I'm making calls to an unmanaged dll from multiple threads created by a bombardment of requests. I don't have access to the dll's source and the dll is not thread safe.

The application works fine when requests are made in serial, however becomes unstable when multiple requests are made in parallel.

My solution thus far has been to try, if fail pause for a short period, retry. This seems to work, however I believe there should be a better way with mutexes or with the Windows API, or some other unknown-to-me solution.

Example of my code:

```cs
public class CDFReader : IDisposable
{
    public CDFReader(string path)
    {
        // open cdf file using dll
    }

    // other cdf extraction methods exist that require the dll
}


public class SomeOtherClass
{
    // function call to CDFReader that gets called from
    // multiple request threads
    public Records GetRecords()
    {
        using (var cdf = CDFReader(somefilepath))
        {
            // extract data from cdf using CDFReader methods
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I fix my issue by wrapping the using block in the fail-wait-retry but would like to lock from within CDFReader. That way anything done with CDFReader is handled automatically rather than locking around the using block.

I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: Yes, a mutex can help here, have you tried using one? You would need to use a "named system mutex", but [MSDN has examples for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I've tried using the "lock" mechanism and also mutex within CDFReader to no real progress. I could be misusing it or misunderstanding it. Let me take a look at your link.

Comment: `lock` would not be appropriate here as it only locks locally (not system-wide).

Comment: Yeah I remember realizing that. Does mutex need to be global to the entire application or just within CDFReader?

Comment: It needs to be global to the *system*, which is why you need to use a named mutex. Web applications are multi-process so `CDFReader` may be used in multiple processes but you need to synchronize access across them all, so the mutex needs to be system global. You can declare/use it in just that one method, but it being a named mutex makes it a system one.

Comment: Also, maybe it's a misunderstanding of the way ASP.NET handles the requests. I'm assuming each request that the application is receiving is spawning a new thread. I could be wrong on that.

Comment: @RonBeyer Is the 'Edit' a reasonable usage of mutex? Also in the MSDN example it disposes of the mutex. Should I do that from CDFReader?

Comment: No, you should be using a named mutex. You are using a local mutex (unnamed). I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Named Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Mutex__ctor_System_Boolean_System_String_) to lock the use of the DLL to this process. The only class that needs it is `CDFReader`, but you need to make sure to dispose of `CDFReader` when you are done using it to avoid obtaining the lock and never releasing it.

```
public class CDFReader : IDisposable
{
    private Mutext _myMutex = new Mutex(false, "CDFDLLMutex");

    public CDFReader(string path)
    {
        _myMutex.WaitOne();   //This locks the DLL for the life of the CDFReader
        // open cdf file using dll
    }

    // other cdf extraction methods exist that require the dll

    //In your dispose method (because this class is IDisposable) call _myMutex.ReleaseMutex() and _myMutex.Dispose()
}


public class SomeOtherClass
{
    // function call to CDFReader that gets called from
    // multiple request threads
    public Records GetRecords()
    {
        //No modification needed to this method
        using (var cdf = CDFReader(somefilepath))
        {
            // extract data from cdf using CDFReader methods
        }
    }
}
```

I show above using the mutex for the life of `CDFReader`. Since you say that it is not "thread safe" for the DLL, I'm not sure if you want the mutex for the entire life of the `CDFReader`, or if you can lock just in the individual method calls.

If you want to lock individual method calls, just call (including in the constructor):

```
public void CDFMethod()
{
    _myMutex.WaitOne();    //With optional timeout
    //Do your processing in the method
    _myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

But still be sure to `.Dispose` of the mutex when `CDFReader` is disposed.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I didn't realize "named mutex" was a thing. This would explain why I wasn't able to get them to work on my initial attempts awhile back.